# Vitali Covering Lemma

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose E is a set of finite outer measure and F is a collection of closed bounded intervals that covers E in the sense of vitali. Then for each $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite disjoint subcollection $(I_k)$ of F such that $$m^*(E-(I_1\cup ...\cup I_n))<\epsilon$$.

Assume this holds, show that
$$m^*(E-(I_1\cup ...\cup I_n ...))=0$$
holds for infinite number of I

Answer (score 0):

Choose $I_{k1},I_{k2},....,I_{kn_k}$ such that $m^{*}(E\setminus \cup_i I_{ki}) <\frac  1 k$. Now arrnage the intervals $I_{k1},I_{k2},....,I_{kn_k}, k=1,2,3,...$ in a single sequence $I_1,I_2,...$. This has the required property.